# Create a Mobx model with dynamic properties (like a map)

Tags: javascript, mobx

A typical Mobx model is a class with a set of keys that are each observable, for example:

```
import { observable, computed } from "mobx";

class OrderLine {
    @observable price = 0;
    @observable amount = 1;

    @computed get total() {
        return this.price * this.amount;
    }
}
```

However, this assumes that I know beforehand which keys my model might have. But in my use case, my model has only one fixed key, and the rest will be dynamic - the user will be able to add extra keys. How should I define my model? Should I make it a subclass of ObservableMap?

```
import { observable } from "mobx";

class Bookmark {
    @observable tags = [];

    # This has to allow additional properties to be added to the object but still be observable
    # e.g. bookmark.foo = "bar"
}
```